# DataTable cannot click the button after pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have done a datatable and custom it's data but when i click the button on the first column, it only works on the first page and cannot click on other forward pages.

```
$('#tbl').DataTable( {
   responsive: true,
   data: data1,
   autoWidth: false,
   "order": [[ 7, "asc" ]],
   "iDisplayLength": 5,
   "pagingType": "full_numbers",
   "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
   "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable":     "Not Record"
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 6,7,8 ] }
    ],
    "columns": [
        {},{"sClass": "dt-body-justify"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}
    ]
} );
```

BUT when for the click function in live mode, it still cannot work

```
$('#tbl tbody tr #edit_current_product').delegate('a', 'click', function () {
    ....... 
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`'s must be unique. We dont know your markup but

```
$('#tbl tbody tr #edit_current_product').delegate('a', 'click', function ()
```

seems utterly wrong. Either you have multiple `<a>`'s with the same id `#edit_current_product` or the right thing actually happens, you have paginated away from the page where `#edit_current_product` is present.

I guess that what you really want is

```
$('#tbl').on('click', 'tbody tr a', function()
```

or use a class instead of an `id`

```
$('#tbl').on('click', 'tbody tr .edit_current_product', function()
```

---

BTW, why

```
"columnDefs": [
    { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 6,7,8 ] }
],
"columns": [
    {},{"sClass": "dt-body-justify"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}
]
```

you just need

```
"columnDefs": [
    { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 6,7,8 ] },
    { "sClass": "dt-body-justify", targets : [1] }
]
```

Comment: It can success click on other pages of the table, Thank you so much!!!!

But now have another problem occurs, the data retrieved on the same row is different. For example, first page maximum is five row, on the second page, when I click the first row, it still give me the first row data of the first page, not first row data of the second page.

Comment: var rowindex=$(this).closest('tr').index();
                var data1 = $('#tbl').DataTable().row( this.row_selected ).columns(8).data();
                var a= data1[0][rowindex];

Comment: @EliceEe - this is because `$(this).closest('tr').index();`  give you the **jQuery** DOM index, you need the **dataTables** index -> `table.row(this).index()` (if it is inside a tr-click handler)